# Yahoo Weather API Oauth C#

Tags: c#, oauth, yahoo-weather-api

I'm having a bit of an issue with the Yahoo Weather API currently. We are using a try catch when feeding the correct information into the query, and the break points show the correct WOEID being fetched, however it will not return the data to the label we provide for the Temperature Data.

I have been searching all day to find anything out, and I've read that the Public API has been turned off, and we must now use OAuth to complete this.

I have my Secret Key and Consumer Key, but I'm not sure how to integrate them into the cs file so that the query will be accepted.

Can anyone provide any information? I can give code examples if needed. I would be most appreciative for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I still could not find an answer to this and have moved onto using Google's Open Weather Map. If anyone has any questions about using the Open Weather Map API, let me know and I will share what information I have. I am using C# and XML for the calls.

Thanks.